# App no longer shows in the LiveWare manager

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

Some of my apps are reported to either suddenly disappear from the LiveWare manager's list of apps (for the SmartWatch 1) or not appear at all. Any idea what the problem might be?

This is not happening always, neither on all devices, and reinstalling the app / LiveWare manager / SmartWatch does not always help. It appears mostly (or only) on Android < 4 devices running LiveWare manager (and SmartWatch 1).

When the error occurs, the LiveWare manager doesn't register the Control of the app, nor the AHA, the Emulator shows this status for the app:

```
AHA: 
Notific.   Widget       Control      Sensor
0            0               0                0
```

I repeat that the same app works on most of the devices also running LiveWare and SmartWatch 1, and there the LiveWare normally detects both the AHA and the required control version.

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: Here are the requested version details. These are just for one case, but there are several similar cases.

> ```
> Smartwatch version is 0.1.B.1.3
> Host Application version s 1.3.3.2
> Phone is a Motorola Defy+ running Android 2.3.4.
> ```

What has been tried until now, and didn't solve the problem:

- Reinstalling the app itself
- Reinstalling the SmartWatch app
- Reinstalling the LiveWare manager
- Restarting the phone

I can confirm that the above recipe solved these kind of problems on my phone / watch, but it was reported to me that it didn't work for other users, one of which had also an Emulator installed, and who sent me the status shown above, so it's not someone who would not know how to do these steps properly.

EDIT2: I don't think this could be the cause, but just to rule out the possibility that my app actually causes this problem; in the manifest xml, the app has

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

While the RegistrationInformation class says:

```
  @Override
  public int getRequiredWidgetApiVersion() {
    return API_NOT_REQUIRED;
  }

  @Override
  public int getRequiredNotificationApiVersion() {
    return API_NOT_REQUIRED;
  }

  @Override
  public int getRequiredControlApiVersion() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public int getTargetControlApiVersion() {
    return 2;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean controlInterceptsBackButton() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int getRequiredSensorApiVersion() {
    return API_NOT_REQUIRED;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isDisplaySizeSupported(int width, int height) {
    return (width == SubcontrolWriter.getSupportedControlWidth(mContext) && height == SubcontrolWriter.getSupportedControlHeight(mContext))
        || (width == SubcontrolWriter2.getSupportedControlWidth(mContext) && height == SubcontrolWriter2.getSupportedControlHeight(mContext));
  }

  @Override
  public ContentValues getExtensionRegistrationConfiguration() {
    String icon = ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.icon);
//    String iconHost = ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.icon_host);
    String icon48 = ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.icon48);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.CONFIGURATION_ACTIVITY,
        SmsPreferenceActivity.class.getName());
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.CONFIGURATION_TEXT,
        mContext.getString(R.string.menu_settings));
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.NAME,
        mContext.getString(R.string.extension_name));
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.EXTENSION_KEY,
        SmsExtensionService.EXTENSION_KEY);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.HOST_APP_ICON_URI, icon);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.EXTENSION_ICON_URI, icon);
    values.put("extension48PxIconUri", icon48); // Registration.ExtensionColumns.EXTENSION_48PX_ICON_URI
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.NOTIFICATION_API_VERSION,
        getRequiredNotificationApiVersion());
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.PACKAGE_NAME,
        mContext.getPackageName());

    return values;
  }
```

EDIT 3: Here's one other configuration:

```
Sony Ericsson Xperia mini Pro SK17i
Android 2.3.4 
SmartWatch version: 1.3.31 
LiveWare Manager version: 3.3.10 
SmartWatch firmware: 0.1.B.1.3
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about which devices specifically, which version of LiveWare/SmartConnect/HostApp, and what software (firmware) version the SW1 is running?

Comment: "my apps" is apps you've made right? This does not affect apps from the market?

Comment: @weston my apps are already on the market and doing fine.

Comment: @MarlinSONY I said that it appears mostly on Android < v.4, so there is no SmartConnect for those devices, they use the LiveWare manager app.

Comment: You missunderstand me, do these problems affect apps that are not written by you?

Comment: @weston yes, it does. I didn't misunderstand you, you clearly asked "apps from the market".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

- Unpair all Smartwatch devices in Settings>Bluetooth
- Clear data for Smart Connect App
- Clear data for Smartwatch 2 host app
- Restart your Smartwatch
- Now pair the device, reconnect and check if it shows up your app. This might be a result of corrupt data in Smartwatch or SmartConnect apps where the extensions are listed.

Comment: Ok, I will report back as soon as I have any feedback if this method worked. But, what about the cases where the app is installed for the first time, and it still doesn't appear in the list of apps?

Comment: @Eir for those case check you have the correct permissions in the manifest.

Comment: @weston if the correct permissions were not in the manifest, that would be a problem on all devices, not only on just a few.

Comment: @Anup - SONY: I just received feedback from the user, he followed the instructions you gave, but still the app is not showing on his watch. And it was working fine until few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Sony seems to have changed the Liveware app so that it no longer works with Android 2.3? My old Smartwatch 1 is not working anymore. I wonder if there is any way to get the old version of Liveware?